# Angular 2: Select a link by default when page loads after login

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I select a link by default when home page loads after login? There are a couple of links on the sidebar and I want one of the link to selected by default.
All these links have `click` functions associated with them. I want `click` function to be instantiated when page loads.

I have tried:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.getElementById('focusLink').focus();
  }
```

But it does not `selects` the link and calls the function.
It is dynamic menu which changes based on who is logged in. I wouldn't know which url to call when page loads. 
The only thing I know is that first link of menu should be selected by default. All the links call to the same function based on the url associated with them.

Each sidebar link has a route associated with it. Onlick calls follwoing function:

```
private subMenuClick(link) {
    this.topBarHeading = link.heading;
    //load the url
    if (!link.sub) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(link.href);
      this.routeUrl = link.href;
      return;
    }
    //open close menu
    this.mainNavigation.forEach(el => {
      if ((el !== link) && el.open && !el.sub.indexOf(link)) {
        el.open = false;
      }
    });

    link.open = !link.open;
    return false;
  };
```

Comment: 1. You should call the method associated with the link. If it is a URL than do something with that url directly in your method. There is no reason to try to activate a link on the page. What is it you are *actually* trying to accomplish? Navigation perhaps? 2. `But it did not work.` <= this is one of the most useless descriptions people post on a daily basis, it tells us nothing of meaning. Please elaborate, what *exactly* happens when your code executes.

Comment: select a link or `setFocus` on a link?

Comment: By `first link of menu should be selected` do you mean set focus or do you mean you want to redirect to the url address in the link?

Comment: I want link's css to change to `selected` and load the url address, because it fills up rest of the page.

Comment: `because it fills up rest of the page` <= Please elaborate. How does this fill up a page? Do you want the browser to simply redirect to this URL in the address bar or do you want some angular component / directive to be loaded asynchronously?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: These two sort of contradicts each other? ***I wouldn't know which url to call when page loads.*** and ***The only thing I know is that first link of menu should be selected by default*** which is it? If you know it's the first, why not call `subMenuClick(link)` with the "first link" in ngOnInit? But as others have mentioned, it's totally unclear what should happen here ;)